# Getting Error while upgrading Integral UI Tree from v19 to v20, in angular 9 application

Tags: angular, treeview

I have an angular 8 application which used IntegralUI Web v19. I am now upgrading the application to angular 9, and plan to upgrade it further. During the upgradation process, I replaced the subfolder of IntegralUI Web v19, with subfolder of IntegralUI Web v20. I am able to build and compile my application, but I get the following error in the console, and my application is not rendered.

`Uncaught (in promise): Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead.`
`Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead.`

My application was working properly before upgradation. Any help would be really appreciated.

I have tried following the documentation as well as solutions stated in github issues, but was not able to find the exact issue. I tried using it through npm install, but that also gave error as stated in [this](https://github.com/lidorsystems/integralui-web-angular/issues/18) github issue.